# How does the transpose of high-dimensional arrays work?

Tags: python, numpy

It's easy to understand the concept of Transpose in 2-D array. I reall can not understand  How  the transpose of high-dimensional arrays works.
For example

```
c = np.indices([4,5]).T.reshape(20,1,2)
d = np.indices([4,5]).reshape(20,1,2)
np.all(c==d) # output is False
```

Why are the outputs of C and D inconsistent?

Comment: This operation is also inconsistent in 2d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [143]: c = np.indices([4,5])
In [144]: c
Out[144]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])

In [145]: c.shape
Out[145]: (2, 4, 5)

In [146]: c.T.shape
Out[146]: (5, 4, 2)
```

Look at one 2d array from the size 2 dimension:

```
In [150]: c[0,:,:]
Out[150]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [151]: c.T[:,:,0]
Out[151]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

The 2nd is the usual 2d transpose, a (5,4) array.

MATLAB doesn't do transpose on 3d arrays, at least it doesn't call it such.  It may have a way making such a change.  `numpy`, using a general shape/strides multidimensional implementation, easily generalizes the 2d transpose - to 1d or 3d or more.